# The meaning of a 'punctual atom'?

Tags: terminology, crystals

This [document](http://spiralconnect.univ-lyon1.fr/spiral-files/download?mode=inline&data=3774403) refers in the to a 'punctual atom' in the context of neutron diffraction from crystals. I have nether come across this term before. What does it mean and how common is it as a phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One definition of punctual is "pertaining to or of the nature of a point". (Admittedly it's the third definition at one source...  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/punctual)

So, rather than being a specific physics phrase, it could just be a way of using an obscure meaning of a common word to talk about "the atom, treated as a point"